# Import, Join and create a dataset

Tags: join, import, dataset

I use 500 csv files which are all in the same folder but have unique names and my goal is to import them and join them to one dataset, so I can compute with it.

So far I use this code:

Data=Join[Data, Import["Data-1.csv", "Dataset"]];
Data=Join[Data, Import["Data-2.csv", "Dataset"]];
...

but for 500 csv files, it is quite exhausting to do so, is there a better way?